# Magento 2 TinyMce Editor in fronend PHTML file example

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, frontend, magento2

TinyMCE not working in magento 2 FrontEnd [PHTML] file

I tried this code

```
 require(["jquery", 'Magento_Theme/js/creamondoModal', "mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup"], function (jQuery, creamondoModal) {
    var config, editor;
    config = {
        settings: {
            mode: 'textarea',
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|," +
                    "fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: null,
            theme_advanced_buttons3: null,
            theme_advanced_buttons4: null,
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: null
        }
    };
    editor = new tinyMceWysiwygSetup('about_course_provider', config);
    editor.turnOn();
    editor = new tinyMceWysiwygSetup('about_vendor', config);
    editor.turnOn();
    editor = new tinyMceWysiwygSetup('vendor_strength', config);
    editor.turnOn();
});
```

This code is working on Chrome But not on **Firefox** and **IE-11**, Edge.

Plz suggest Thanks in advance.... :)

Answer (score 0):

You should get configuration from magento and re-set them

```
protected $wysiwyg;
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwyg
    ){
    $this->wysiwyg = $wysiwyg;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

...

```
public function getWysiwygConfig(){
    $config = $this->wysiwyg->getConfig();
    $config->setData('add_variables', false);
    $config->setData('add_widgets', false);
    $config->addData([
        'settings' => [
            'mode' => 'textarea',
            'theme_advanced_buttons1' => "bold,italic,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,|,bullist,numlist,|,code",
            'theme_advanced_buttons2' => NULL,
            'theme_advanced_buttons3' => NULL,
            'theme_advanced_buttons4' => NULL,
            'theme_advanced_statusbar_location' => NULL
        ]
    ]);
    return $config;
}
```

...

```
require(["jquery", "mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup"], function (jQuery) {
    var editor;
    editor = new tinyMceWysiwygSetup('text', <?php echo \Zend_Json::encode($this->getWysiwygConfig()); ?>);
    editor.turnOn();
});
```